# Whatsapp message template with status Active – Quality pending couldn't be sent. Getting "(#132001) Template name does not exist in the translation"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, whatsapp-cloud-api

```json
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#132001) Template name does not exist in the translation",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 132001,
        "error_data": {
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "details": "template name (message_request) does not exist in en_US"
        },
        "fbtrace_id": "A_EjJh2lU36b3yKxpX9q8WD"
    }
}
```

We have successfully created a message template having 2 buttons in WhatsApp manager under meta business settings.

```
Name of the template: message_request 
Language: English (US)
Status: Active – Quality pending
```

While trying the graph API to send message to user, we get error.

Request:

```json
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "to": "913456666661",
  "type": "template",
  "template": {
        "name": "message_request",
        "language": {
            "code": "en_US"
        }
  }
}
```

Response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#132001) Template name does not exist in the translation",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 132001,
        "error_data": {
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "details": "template name (message_request) does not exist in en_US"
        },
        "fbtrace_id": "A_EjJh2lU36b3yKxpX9q8WD"
    }
}
```

What is causing this issue?

Comment: I also have this issue. I made sure the language code is correct and the template is approved. Maybe it has to do with outages of the [on-premises solution](https://metastatus.com/whatsapp-business-api)

Comment: Any solution? Have the same problem

Comment: I have same problem. did you find any solution?

Comment: @RajendraAVerma, I have the same issue, That is, previously I sent the template with that code without problems and now I get this error. I don't understand what's happening

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the language code specified in the API call (en_US in this case) matches the language you set for the template in the WhatsApp manager. Sometimes it takes time for the template to propagate through the system. If you've recently created or modified the template, consider waiting a bit longer. Is the template fully approved and active?
When I was working through an ISP partner, I had this error a lot. I contacted their support, they forced synchronization of the template with FB Templates.

Comment: I have created this template before 2 weeks and it is in status: Active – Quality pending. And I have read in the documentation that we can use the template in this state.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I have the same problem, I don't know what to try

Answer (score 0):

I've went through this error. I was creating the template in a whatsapp phone number account and trying to use it from another one.

Make sure that You've craeted the template in the Same whatsapp account number you are using.

Open the templates page :

Choose the account you want to send messages through.
and start creating it from this step.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euXwR.png)